# Empty Element xml load stops

Tags: if-statement, getelementsbytagname, isnullorempty

i'm trying to display een xml file in een html page but when a tagname has an empy null value it stops at that point and wont display the rest of the file

```
<script>
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","./test.XML",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

 document.write("<table border='0'>");
 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   { 
  document.write("<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=table><tr><td>"+
    "<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class=table>"+
    "<tr><td width=6%></td><td align=left>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("nr")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"<br><br></td><td></td><td align=left>text<br><br></td></tr>"+
    "<tr><td align=left>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("nrorder")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td>");

    if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].length = 0)
    {
        document.write("<td></td>");
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("<td align=left><b>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</b></td>");

    }

    }
 </script>
 </center>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here the test xml file

```
 <file>
 <nr>1</nr>
 <nrorder>101</nrorder>
 <text>1</text>
 </file>
 <file>
 <nr>2</nr>
 <nrorder>102</nrorder>
 <text></text>
 </file>
 <file>
 <nr>33333333333</nr>
 <nrorder>103</nrorder>
 <text>33333333</text>
 </file>
```

So when i get to  of 2 it does not go on to  3. How can i or move on to the next one? without stopping at the second

if i remove the if statment i can display everything but need this element

the fix is:

```
if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
    document.write("<td align=left><b></b></td>")
} 
else {
    document.write("<td align=left><b>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</b></td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {
document.write("<td align=left><b></b></td>")
} 
else {
document.write("<td align=left><b>"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</b></td>");
```

}